# CLI update for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to update Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 and 2019 from the command line (more specifically, from a Jenkins agent).

Updating VS itself works fine with

```
vs_installer.exe update --quiet--installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
vs_installer.exe update --quiet--installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
```

except if the installer needs to be updated, because then it will just hang asking the user to confirm updating the installer (and for some reason it still opens a window in `--quiet` mode if it can).

The [documented-ish](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f1825d6-8af5-420a-a8da-e9573ccae8d9/using-command-line-to-silently-upgrade-just-the-installer-in-visual-studio-2017-152?forum=vssetup)

```
vs_installer.exe --update --quiet
```

no longer works with the installer that ships with 2019 (the `--update` option is unknown).

Comment: quiet most certainly is applicable, **vs_enterprise.exe update --wait --passive --norestart --installPath "C:\installPathVS"** Care to provide the output of the command your running preferably as a screenshot cause your supplied command has an error in it. [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/command-line-parameter-examples?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

So, the update with community 2017-2019-2022 works as fine as with Enterprise 2017-2019-2022

Try the command with the --passive argument like this (It works with Visual Studio 2017)

```
call "Path:\to\File\vs_installer.exe" update --passive --norestart --installpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
```

Info: the Install path shown here is the standard path of VS, choose another if needed.

With Visual Studio 2019 we needed to put it in a powershell command like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path_to\vs_installer.exe" -ArgumentList "update",'--installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"',"--passive","--norestart" -Wait
```

And also for  Visual Studio Community 2022 like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path_to\vs_installer.exe" -ArgumentList "update",'--installPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"',"--passive","--norestart" -Wait
```

And also one thing, you can update Visual Studio 2022 with the vs_installer.exe of VS2019.

Nota Bene: Maybe you will need to restart the machine after the Installation is done, because the update just after the installation can fail (I dont know why), but the update command shurely works because we do it all the time.

PS: Just seen the post now after on year. I thought I still reply because it can help others.
Best Regards.